# BootstrapJS - Nav Nav-list not collapsing on click.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Stumped on another one. I'm using boostrapJS to create a Nav-List. Ideally the headers will remain collapsed by default, but will expand when clicked. Right now I have some javascript that will go and dynamically populate the List, but the click event seems to be doing nothing. (sort of - I click on the header and it jitters a bit, but it does not collapse).

I've looked at the code examples, and I'm pretty sure I'm using the same classes and div structure, but It still seems to be not working, and it's not throwing any errors.

Here is my Code:

```
        $('#header').append('<ul class="nav nav-list">');
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            k = keys[i];
            $('#header').append('<label class="tree-toggle nav-header">' + keys[i] + '</label>');
            for (var j in groupedtemplates[k]) {
                $('#header').append('<a href="#"><li data-value=' + groupedtemplates[k][j].id + '>' + groupedtemplates[k][j].attributes.im_name.value + '</li></a>');
            }
        }
        $('#header').append('</ul>');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tree-toggle').click(function () {
                $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
            });
        });
```

The HTML that it's being inserted into is just a simple container.

```
    <div class="well" style="width:100%; padding: 8px 0;" id="header">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

When you append a tag without a closing tag, the browser inserts one for you. Because of this the objects were not appearing as children.

This is my revised solution that puts all the data to be appended in a variable, then appends it afterwards.

```
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            k = keys[i];
            var toAppend = "";
            toAppend = toAppend + '<ul class="nav nav-list">' + '<li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header">' + keys[i] + '</label</li>' + '<ul class="nav nav-list tree">'
            for (var j in groupedtemplates[k]) {
                toAppend = toAppend + '<a href="#"><li data-value=' + groupedtemplates[k][j].id + '>' + groupedtemplates[k][j].attributes.im_name.value + '</li></a>'
            }
            toAppend = toAppend + "</ul></ul>";
            $('#header').append(toAppend);
        }
```